# wordpress shortcode url decode non Latin character

Tags: shortcode, urls, encoding, htmlspecialchars-decode

I am using a shortcode to call some posts with a permalink using non Latin characters.

However the urls get percent encoded ( showing up as %20%regfd etc)
What is the best way to make sure urls are decoded in the front?

I noticed then adding some space before the link, the urls also shows up decoded. But I don't think this is the best solution.

```
<a href=" '.$url.'">
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to look at the PHP function `rawurldecode`, which decodes URL-encoded strings. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php

For example, `echo rawurldecode(get_permalink($post->ID));` will show the decoded post URL. But this isn't really needed in hyperlink code.

*Sorry I didn't just write a comment, I don't have enough points for that option.*